# Rails, title fields that contains IDs to multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

So I have three models in a simple one to one relationship.

```
A
B
C
```

C can be a child of their A or B, but never both, so it only needs to be stored in one field.

In the C model, should it have a field titled `a_or_b_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C model, I would have two fields:
One containing the id of the A or B parent,
and the other identifying whether the record belongs to A or B

Since the same id could appear in both a and b, if you went with the a_or_b_id field only it would be unclear which model the c record belongs to

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for polymorphic associations, better than a long answer I prefer to point you to the official guides:

Rails 3 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Rails 4 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations